# ASN.1 Length encoding (using BER)

Tags: asn.1

This should be pretty basic but, I've been scratching my head around it for some time, so I thought I should ask around, so thanks in advance for the help.

So my question is, I have this sequence:

```
User::=SEQUENCE {
userid [0] IA5String,
password [1] Implicit IA5String}
```

And I want to encode the following using BER, having the following values:

```
{userid = "user", password = "pass"}
```

So we have the 3 "fields" TLV:

```
Tag is: 001 10000
```

My question is the Length itself, which should be `08` (I think `04` bytes from "user" plus `04` bytes from "pass").

But in the solutions I have:

```
L -> 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 (=14)  0E
```

And I can't seem able to find out why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in BER and DER encoding rules, each data element is encoded as a Tag-Length-Value sequence.

When talking about a not-constructed type (e.g. INTEGER or IA5String) value is the actual value encoded following the rules for that type.

When talking about a constructed type (e.g. SEQUENCE or SET) value is the BER/DER encoded value of the different *fields* included within the constructed type.

With that in mind we can take your type

```
User::=SEQUENCE {
    userid [0] IA5String,
    password [1] IMPLICIT IA5String}
```

and your data value

```
{userid = "user", password = "pass"}
```

We can start to encode.

First will go the tag for the SEQUENCE, which is 0x30, then it would go the length, which we don't know yet. Now we should encode the value of the constructed SEQUENCE. So we start encoding the different fields.

We need to encode the `userid` field. This is a tagged type, here, depending on the global `EXPLICIT` or `IMPLICIT` options this could be constructed or not:
- If EXPLICIT, we will have the tag 0xA0 (for constructed-context 0), the length and then tagged type: IA5String is tag 0x16 (UNIVERSAL 22), its length 0x04 and its value 0x75 73 65 72
- If IMPLICIT, we will have the tag 0x80 (for non-constructed context 0), the length 0x04 and the value 75 73 65 72

Finally, we need to encode the password, in this case we don't have doubts, IMPLICIT keyword is added to force the implicit tagging. So we will have the tag 0x81 (for non constructed context 1), the length 0x04 and the value 70 61 73 73

So in summary we have (assuming global IMPLICIT)

```
30 0c
   80 04 75 73 65 72
   81 04 70 61 73 73
```

totalling 14 bytes

or if global EXPLICIT

```
30 0e
   A0 06
      16 04 75 73 65 72
   81 04 70 61 73 73
```

totalling 16 bytes

Comment: Hi! Could you please throw some light as length 12 bytes (=1+1+1+1+5+1+1+1) calculated in accordance with your procedure differs from published, 10 bytes : 
...
If of type:
SEQUENCE {name IA5String, ok BOOLEAN}
the value:
{name "Smith", ok TRUE}
can be encoded as:
 Sequence Length  Contents
 3016   0A16
   IA5String  Length  Contents
   1616   0516  "Smith"
   Boolean  Length  Contents
   0116   0116  FF16
...

Comment: @AVA, Sorry I don't follow you. I've gathered that you refer to the example of page 13 on X.209 or the example in page 10 of X.690. Both are the same and they use 2 bytes on TL of sequence + 7 bytes on TLV of "Smith" and 3 bytes on TLV of TRUE, totalling 12 bytes

Answer (score 0):

`userid` payload is 4 bytes, plus 1 byte for payload length (4) and tag (IA5String). This results 6 bytes TLV. `password` value is 4 bytes, plus 1 byte for payload length (4) and tag (IA5String). Payload size for SEQUENCE is 12 bytes. Add length byte (12) and tag (SEQUENCE) and you will get 14 bytes structure.

More info on Microsoft web site: [DER Transfer Syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb540801(v=vs.85).aspx), [Encoded Length and Value Bytes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb648641(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Hey, could you please elaborate a little further ? You are adding +2 bytes for payload length and tag, but why? Isn't the length supposed to be the size of the data we want to transmite ( and thus only 8 bytes ) ? For instance if i want to transmite the number 45, the length is only `01`because `45 = 101101` and thus only 1 octet. Thanks for you help!

Comment: look at the provided links. Each component is encoded in TLV triplets. Each triplet consist of tag (to determine what is stored in the payload), one or more bytes that identifies payload length and actual payload data.

Comment: no, it is not possible to send pure 8 bytes because data recipient will be unable to differentiate `userid` and `password` fields. In the case you want to send 45 as integer, then your encoded data will be 3 bytes: 0x02 0x01 0x2d, where 0x02 -- is the tag (INTEGER), 0x01 -- payload length (1 byte) and 0x2d -- actual data.

Comment: I think I didn't express myself correctly sorry about that.
What I'm not understading is only the length on the first case. If I want to transmit the number 45 is pretty straightforward:

`TAG - 000 00010 (02)
Length - 000 00001 (01, because 45 is less than 1 octet)
Value - 00101101 (45)`

My question is that "user" has a length of `04` bytes and so does "pass".
So the payload should be `08` bytes, but it's actually `14`. I wanted to know how could i see where the remaining 6 bytes come from and why.

On the first problem:
`TAG - 001 10000 (16-SEQUENCE)
Length - It's 000 01110` but how? Thanks

Comment: @RedFoxxie, you're missing the overhead of the Tag Length of the fields within the sequence. I hope my answer provides the right level of detail...

Answer (score 0):

Note that the elements of the sequence are tagged, the first one explicitly (meaning an "extra" tag/length before the full IA5String encoding), the second implicitly (meaning a tag/length that replaces the original IA5String tag/length).

So, the full encoding would be 300ea006160475736572810470617373:

```
30 CONSTRUCTED SEQUENCE
0e Length 14
a0 CONSTRUCTED TAGGED 0
06 Length 6
16 IA5String
04 Length 4
75 'u'
73 's'
65 'e'
72 'r'
81 TAGGED 1
04 Length 4
70 'p'
61 'a'
73 's'
73 's'
```

Note that an ASN.1 module definition *could* declare tags implicit by default, but I'm assuming that's not the case as you mention existing solutions which also give length 14 for the SEQUENCE tag.

Answer (score 0):

```
package binaryhex;

public class BinaryHex {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "A8 59 A0 47 A0 15 80 01 01 81 02 01 F4 82 01 01 83 09 31 32 37 2E 30 2E 30 2E 31 81 07 32 33 30 5F 32 32 37 82 0E 32 30 31 36 30 38 32 32 31 34 35 36 31 30 83 01 00 84 01 00 A5 0F 80 03 44 53 4D 81 08 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 81 0E 32 30 31 36 30 38 32 32 31 34 35 36 31 30";
        String hexDumpStrWithoutSpace = s.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
        int length = calculateLength(hexDumpStrWithoutSpace);
        System.out.println("LENGTH: " + length);
    }

    private static int calculateLength(String hexDumpStrWithoutSpace) {
        int decimalValue = 0;
        boolean tag = false;
        int i = 0;
        while (!tag) {
            String typeSub = hexDumpStrWithoutSpace.substring(i, i + 2);
            StringBuilder typeBinSB = new StringBuilder();
            for (int j = 0; j < typeSub.length(); j++) {
                typeBinSB.append(hexToBinary("" + typeSub.charAt(j)));
            }
            String typeBin = typeBinSB.toString();
            if (typeBin.charAt(2) == '0') {
                int tagInt = Integer.parseInt(typeBin.substring(3), 2);
                System.out.println("TAG: " + tagInt);
                tag = true;
            } else {
                String tagStr = typeBin.substring(3 - i / 2);
                if (tagStr.equals("11111")) {
                    i = i + 2;
                    continue;
                } else {
                    int tagInt = Integer.parseInt(tagStr, 2);
                    System.out.println("TAG: " + tagInt);
                    tag = true;
                    i = i + 2;
                }

            }
        }

        for (; i < hexDumpStrWithoutSpace.length();) {
            String lengthSub = hexDumpStrWithoutSpace.substring(i, i + 2);

            StringBuilder lengthBinSB = new StringBuilder();
            for (int j = 0; j < lengthSub.length(); j++) {
                lengthBinSB.append(hexToBinary("" + lengthSub.charAt(j)));
            }
            String lengthBin = lengthBinSB.toString();
            if (lengthBin.charAt(0) == '0') {
                Integer lengthInt = Integer.parseInt(lengthBin, 2);
                decimalValue = lengthInt + i;
                break;
            } else {
                Integer lengthOctets = Integer.parseInt(lengthBin.substring(1), 2);
                StringBuilder toBinSB = new StringBuilder();

                for (int k = 0; k < lengthOctets; k++) {
                    i = i + 2;
                    String toBin = hexDumpStrWithoutSpace.substring(i, i + 2);
                    for (int j = 0; j < toBin.length(); j++) {
                        toBinSB.append(hexToBinary("" + toBin.charAt(j)));
                    }
                }
                String lengthResult = toBinSB.toString();
                Integer lengthValue = Integer.parseInt(lengthResult, 2);
                decimalValue = lengthValue + i - 2;
                break;
            }
        }

        return decimalValue;
    }

    static String hexToBinary(String hex) {
        int i = Integer.parseInt(hex, 16);
        String bin = Integer.toBinaryString(i);
        if (bin.length() < 4) {
            while (bin.length() < 4) {
                bin = "0" + bin;
            }
        }
        return bin;
    }

}
```